# Exclude Category ID in function

Tags: functions, categories, exclude

I have the following code appending an ad block at the end of my posts

```
function info_after_post($content){
if (is_single()) {
$content .= 'AD CODE';
}
return $content;
}
add_filter( 'the_content', 'info_after_post' );
```

I'd like somehow exclude this from executing on post category ID 71 while still executing for all my other post categories and I can't quite figure out how.

I tried this, but couldn't tell if I was going down the right path.

```
function info_after_post($content){
if (is_category( '71' )) {
    $content ;
} else { 
    $content .= 'AD CODE';
}
return $content;
}
add_filter( 'the_content', 'info_after_post' );
```

Much thanks for any help on this!

Answer (score 1):

I think [has_category()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/has_category/) should help you.

```
function info_after_post($content){
if (is_single() && ! has_category(71)) {
$content .= 'AD CODE';
}
return $content;
}
add_filter( 'the_content', 'info_after_post' );
```